# Using promise for array with mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Seems map from json does take time, and I want to wait for it using promise.

```
formatDataOutput: function (jsonData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let a = JSON.parse(jsonData)
        let b = data.b.map(p => ({ store: p[0], surname: p[1] }))
        let l = data.l.map(p => ({ store: p[0], surname: p[1] }))
        let e = data.e.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1] }))
        let eT = data.eT.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1], name: p[2] }))
        let bx = data.bx.map(p => ({ store: p[0], surname: p[1] }))
        let e = data.e.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1] }))
        let eT = data.eT.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1], name: p[2] }))
        let t = data.t.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1] }))
        let tT = data.tT.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1], name: p[2] }))
        let x = data.x.map(p => ({ store: p[0], address: p[1], viewkey: p[2] }))
        let formattedData = {
            b: b,
            l: l,
            e: e,
            eT: eT,
            bx: bx,
            e: e,
            eT: eT,
            t: t,
            tT: tT,
            x: x
        }
        console.log(formattedData) // -> Its correct
        resolve(formattedData)
    })
}


func.formatDataOutput(data).then((formattedData) => {
    reply.send(formattedData) // -> Its {}
})
```

I tried `Promise.all` and it returns non Iterable, basically I need output of the `formattedData`, when it is ready.

Comment: Unless you have any calls that are async (file I/O, API calls), then this will not do anything of value.

Comment: So, how I actually should do it?

Comment: Unless you have other code that needs to continue processing while this is happening, there is no reason not to just do the code and take the time to do it.

Comment: what is the error?